# SQLAlchemy: Sublcass model without creating new table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In a Flask application we currently had to move some classes around and change the imports as well, but for backwards compatibility before we fix older modules we still need to be able to import them from the original place, but want to raise a warning whenever someone tries to use it.

Normally in python I would sublcass it and add a warning into the body like so:

```
from app.data import TableModel as NewTableModel

class TableModel(NewTableModel):
    warnings.warn('OldTableModel is deprecated, use NewTableModel instead', DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
```

But that will produce the following error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers. Triggering mapper: 'mapped class Admin->admin'. Original exception was: Multiple classes found for path "TableModel" in the registry of this declarative base. Please use a fully module-qualified path.
```

So the question is how can one create a subclass of SQLAlchemy table without sqlalchemy registering it into the registry?

Answer (score 1):

All that is needed was to add `__abstract__ = True` for SQLAlchemy to ignore the subclass

```py
from app.data import TableModel as NewTableModel

class TableModel(NewTableModel):
    __abstract__ = True
    warnings.warn('OldTableModel is deprecated, use NewTableModel instead', DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
```

Comment: Deprecation warning is not raised and the TableModel is missing query parameter in this case.